# I move the camera quickly, the image appears to break horizontally

Tags: python, c++, opencv, fullscreen, webcam

I am viewing webcam camera via opencv. When I make the image fullscreen (with opencv fullscreen codes) and I move the camera quickly, the image appears to break horizontally, as in the picture below. There is no problem when I do not do fullscreen, or if I open any window in front of the fullscreen (if the fullscreen stays in the background), there is no problem again.
I couldn't solve the problem, I would be glad if you can help.

Ubuntu 16.04

[image]

Comment: This is tearing, the drawing of your video is not synchronised with the update of the images. Look into double buffering and/or vsync

Comment: I did not fully understand why.
Webcam is running at 25hz rate. Is it because my screen is 60Hz? Is it because the monitor's rate is higher than the camera?

Comment: Also why does this tearing only happen in fullscreen?

Comment: It'll take longer to draw your image in full screen making tearing more likely